# PowerMockito failing to create an instance of a class which has anonymous block

Tags: powermockito

I just converted our application code into simple classes to express the problem concisely. Our use case contains a class which internally uses some helper classes with static methods which needs to be mocked. So, planned to use PowerMockito. No issues with this part, however we have one class where we have an anonymous block inside one of the methods. When we try to create an instance of this class, PowerMockito fails with a very vague error. Tried spending few hours to resolve the issue without any luck.

```
public abstract class AbstractClass {

    public abstract void methodOne(String arg);

    public void methodTwo()
    {
        System.out.println("In method two");
    }
}

public class StaticMethod {

    public static String someStaticMethod()
    {
        System.out.println("in static method");
        return "static";

    }
}

public class AbstractClassCaller {

    public AbstractClassCaller()
    {
        StaticMethod.someStaticMethod();
        // The following piece of code is the problematic block
        AbstractClass abstractClassInstance = new AbstractClass(){
            public void methodOne(String methodArg)
            {
                System.out.println("In Method One");

            }
        };

    }
}

@Test
@PrepareForTest({AbstractClassCaller.class,StaticMethod.class})
public class AbstractClassCallerTest {

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception
    {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(StaticMethod.class);
        PowerMockito.when(StaticMethod.someStaticMethod()).thenReturn(
                "PowerStatic");
        // This is the code which triggers the exception
        AbstractClassCaller instance = new AbstractClassCaller();

    }

    @ObjectFactory
    public IObjectFactory getObjectFactory() {
        return new org.powermock.modules.testng.PowerMockObjectFactory();
    }
}
```

The above junit class fails with the following exception:

```
org.powermock.reflect.exceptions.ConstructorNotFoundException: Failed to lookup constructor with parameter types [ com.oracle.oal.seaas.AbstractClassCaller ] in class com.oracle.oal.seaas.AbstractClassCaller$1.
    at com.oracle.oal.seaas.AbstractClassCallerTest.test(AbstractClassCallerTest.java:21)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.oracle.oal.seaas.AbstractClassCaller$1.<init>(com.oracle.oal.seaas.AbstractClassCaller)
    at com.oracle.oal.seaas.AbstractClassCallerTest.test(AbstractClassCallerTest.java:21)
```

// the following anonymous block in AbstractClassCaller is causing the issue:

```
AbstractClass abstractClassInstance = new AbstractClass(){
            public void methodOne(String methodArg)
            {
                System.out.println("In Method One");

            }
        };
```

Any ideas on how to fix this issue?